# Grafana: Response is failed when try to load as XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to load data from grafana using Javascript XMLHTTPRequest. Following is my code,

```
function populateIframe(  ) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xhr.open('GET', 'http://username:password@localhost:3000/api/org');
          xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
          xhr.send();

          function handler() {
              debugger;
            if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
              if (this.status === 200) {
                // this.response is a Blob, because we set responseType above
                document.getElementById("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
              } else {
                console.error('XHR failed', this);
              }
            }
          }
```

I am getting status code as 0. And i also tried Ajax call to get Grafana response, But still am not getting any proper data. Can someone guide me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the website that includes that script served? From `http://localhost`? Or `http://localhost:3000`? If the former, are you setting CORS headers?

Comment: For basic authentication I am mentioned like above. My goal is to access multiple organizations in grafana by an authenticated manner.

Comment: I asked you two fairly simple questions. If you can't answer them, I can't help you.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am using http://localhost:3000. Am not added CORS header. Even my code changes are not reflected in application.